# JQGRID - JQMODAL: Disable close modal when click on overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqmodal

I am trying to disable close on click when clicking the overlay behind the edit form Modal that opens when I edit a row, but I dont know how I have to do it. I were trying something like:

```
editOptions: {
    url: 'foo/edit.html',
    mtype: 'PUT',

    //some other options
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    onClose: function() {
        alert('Hi ^_^');
    }
}
```

But this only triggers if I click at `'X'` button. If I click at overlay (out of modal) it closes the modal and that alert never triggers. What I want is to disable that closing function when I click out of modal or remove that overlay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's interesting problem. `onClose` callback will be not called if one clicks on the overlay (if one clicks out of the modal dialog) and the dialog will be closed.

It's funny, but `jqModal.js` already has the option which would be perfect to implement your requiremens. It's `closeoverlay` option of `$.fn.jqm` (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/jqModal.js#L16)). The problem is that jqGrid don't have any public property which allows to set the option. If you just modify `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` the `closeoverlay : true` to `closeoverlay : false` (it corresponds changing `closeoverlay:!0` to `closeoverlay:!1` in `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`) then you will have the behavior which you need.

The problem is that I don't see any simple way to realize your requirements without modification of the code jqGrid.

**UPDATED**: I analysed the code of `jqModal.js` module one more time and I'v found simple way *without changing the source code of jqGrid*. The analyse is difficult because the module exist only in minimized form. So it's difficult to read the code.

The solution: you should include the following line which changes defaults of `jqModal.js` module:

```js
$.jqm.params.closeoverlay = false;
```

Description: [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/jqModal.js#L39-L60) of `jqModal.js` module initialize `$.jqm` as

```
$.jqm = {
    hash: {},
    open: function (s,t) { ... },
    close: function (s) { ... },
    params: {}
};
```

So everywhere after you includes `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` you have `$.jqm.params` as empty object. It can be used to provide default values of parameters of `jqModal.js` (which are not directly specified in the list of parameters of `$.jqm`). So you can include `$.jqm.params.closeoverlay = false;` somewhere after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) to deny closing of jqGrid dialog on clicking on the overlay.

Comment: Yeah, It is not an easy way to do that. Also, I thought to suggest it to jqGrid developers. I will check your suggest.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works, but I think they should do an easy way to do that, a new property for example. If you think it's a good idea to suggest to developers, I will suggest them that. Also would like to apologize for don't explaining at other questions I posted before. As I said, thank you! ^_^

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: You are welcome! As I wrote changing of `closeoverlay` in the source is in general not the best way, but it's really the simplest one *in the case*. I'll post the corresponding suggestion later to trirand. The problem is jqModal module are used many many times *internally* in the code of jqGrid. So making the option public in jqGrid method will follow changing on many lines of jqGrid code. One will need just forward the option below to jqModal module.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: I'v found better way to solve the problem: see **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! So I have to add that line at any JS that creates a jqGrid if I want to disable overlays in that specific page instead to change my source and let it disable overlay for any other page? That line it's not a really hard way to implement that, already did some modifications with `$.extend...`, but still thinking that there should be a better and intuitive way.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX: You are welcome! Yes, you need just include `$.jqm.params.closeoverlay = false;` somewhere after `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`): see modified **UPDATED** part.